# How to increase the login access token TTL in Loopback 3.0?

Tags: node.js, api, access-token, loopbackjs, ttl

I am using LoopBack 3.0 for an API project.

Also i am using built in authentication method which includes access_token and login mechanism.

I figured that the default TTL value for Access Token is 500 by changing `AccessToken` model `datasource` to `mysql`.

Now i want to customize the TTL value without re-writing the `/login` API functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```js
User.beforeRemote('login', async (ctx) => {
  ctx.req.body.ttl = ACCESS_TOKEN_TTL
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you could add beforeSave hook for the AccessToken entity and set the ttl value then